# Geometric interpretation to $|Z^2-9| +|Z^2|=41$

Tags: complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics, conic-sections, locus

> If a complex number $Z$ satisfies the equation
> $$|Z^2-9| +|Z^2|=41$$ then prove that locus of $Z$ is an ellipse with centre at origin in the complex plane.

My approach:

One way of solving the question is setting $\,z=x+iy,\, $ but squaring $z$ and squaring it two more times is very lengthy.

So I am guessing that it should have a neat geometric intuition which I can't figure out. Kindly suggest an alternative approach to this question.

Comment: Are you sure that it is $|Z^2 - 9|$ and not $|Z - 9|^2$? (Or perhaps, $|Z-3|^2$?)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yes,I verified it.

Comment: "locus of $Z^2$" is meaningless.  A locus is a set of points that satisfy a system of equations (where such a system may contain only one equation).  There is no equation here.

Comment: @EricTowers: The phrase "locus of $Z^2$" could be reasonably assumed to be the set $\{Z^2 \mid Z \in L\}$ where $L = \{Z \in \Bbb C \mid |Z^2 - 9| + |Z^2| = 41\}.$

Comment: @EricTowers yes,edited

Comment: @AryamanMaithani : Then the construction is "locus of $Z^2$ satisfying the given equation".

Comment: It's definitely an ellipse, just replace $Z^2$ with $Y$, so it is a point whose distances from 0 and 9 add up to a constant. So you know the locus of the square. Can you relate it?

Comment: @EricTowers: I think the case was that the question was asking for the locus of $Z$ and OP was telling their working that they found the "locus of $Z^2$" to be an ellipse.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani : There is no such thing as "the locus of $Z$".  There **is** a "the locus of $Z$ satisfying (equation(s) or reference to previously specified equation(s))".  This is grammatically equvalent to asking for the derivative of $pq$ or the antiderivative of $s \sqrt{t}$.  In all cases, an essential component of the specification is missing.

Comment: @EricTowers - what is wrong with "locus of $Z$" meaning $\{Z \in \mathbb{C} : |Z^2 - 9| + |Z^2| = 41\}$?  This is well defined.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: @antkam : "locus of $Z$" is an incomplete phrase.  Contrast with every non-definitional usage at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(mathematics) where the construction is "the locus of a point [such that] [a property]" and **always** unambiguously specifies the property.  Without the property, the phrase is incomplete; "the locus of $Z$" is not a complete construction.  For instance, at the link, "the locus of a point P that has a given ratio ...", is a correctly constructed declaration of a "locus".  After that specification, "the locus" may be and is used as a pronoun for that locus.

Comment: @EricTowers - I see your point, but the OP problem stmt has only one equation in it, so...

Comment: @antkam : ... since it is not a locus declaration, there is no antecedent for "locus".  This is exactly as malformed as "the derivative of $p q$"...  with respect to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $$g(z)=|z^2-9| +|z^2|=41,\quad z \in \mathbb{C}.$$
Clearly, $g(-z)=g(z)=g(\bar z).$ Therefore, the locus $\mathcal{L}(z)$ we are looking for is symmetric over origin and also over real and imaginary axes.

From $41=16+25=25+16$ we can guess solutions $5,-5,4i,-4i.$
Their position in the plane and the symmetry of $\mathcal{L}(z)$ make me think of an ellipse with center at origin, axes $2a=10$ along real axis and $2b=8$ along imaginary axis.
Foci of this ellipse are in $-3$ and $3,$ $(c^2=a^2-b^2,$ where $c$ is the distance between the center and a focus) and its equation in $\mathbb{C}$ is
$$|z+3|+|z-3|=10.\tag{1}$$
Let us prove that $(1)$ is an equation of $\mathcal{L}(z).$

Squaring $(1)$ gives an equivalent equation, because all terms in $(1)$ are non-negative. Due to [Apollonius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem) we get $$\underbrace{|z+3|^2+|z-3|^2}_{2(|z|^2+9)}+2\cdot\underbrace{|z+3|\cdot |z-3|}_{|(z+3)(z-3)|}=100,$$ or
$$|z^2-9|+|z^2|=41.$$

Comment: Sorry if I am slow this morning -- I just woke up :) -- but can you explain how you got $|z+3|^2 + |z-3|^2 = 2 ( |z|^2 + 9)$?  I could do that if I first write $z = x + iy$ but you seem to be saying it's a well known identity and there is no need to consider Real & Imaginary parts etc.

Comment: It is legitimate to ask for it. I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks!  I have never heard of Apollonius theorem.  Very niche but also very neat!  :)

Comment: Thank you @antkam The theorem is also known as a Median theorem, in french high school math curriculum related to vectors.